# set date depending on values from other fields

Tags: sql-server

Sorry for the Header, I can't find the right way to describe what I want, possibly the reason why I can't get a solution by googling :) ... Here my problem:

I've got a table with the following structure and some example data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[set_dates](
[Split3_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[CU_ID] [int] NULL,
[order_id] [int] NULL,
[st_date] [datetime] NULL,
[sku] [int] NULL,
[Priority] [int] NULL,
[Delay] [int] NULL,
[CourseDate] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[set_dates]
       ([CU_ID]
       ,[order_id]
       ,[st_date]
       ,[sku]
       ,[Priority]
       ,[Delay])
 VALUES
       (25721,7907,GETDATE(),63,4,4),
       (25718,7910,GETDATE(),63,4,4),
       (25718,7910,GETDATE(),6,5,2),
       (25719,7908,GETDATE(),6,5,2),
       (25719,7908,GETDATE(),57,4,4),
       (25719,7908,GETDATE(),52,8,2)
  GO
```

So my Table should look like this:

```
Split3_ID CU_ID order_id st_date                    sku Priority Delay CourseDate

1         25721 7907     2014-07-08 18:04:30.973    63  4        4     NULL
2         25718 7910     2014-07-08 18:04:30.973    63  4        4     NULL
3         25718 7910     2014-07-08 18:04:30.973    6   5        2     NULL
4         25719 7908     2014-07-08 18:04:30.973    6   5        2     NULL
5         25719 7908     2014-07-08 18:04:30.973    57  4        4     NULL
6         25719 7908     2014-07-08 18:04:30.973    52  8        2     NULL
```

What I would like to accomplish now is to set the CourseDate depending on three fields, order_id, Priority and Delay ... more exact:

If there is only one row with the same order_id, then CourseDate = st_date, if there is multiple rows with the same order_id, then the Dates should be entered depending on the Priority. Lowest Priority would be the first CourseDate = st_date, next bigger Priority would be st_date + Delay from previous entry ... and so on ...

In the above example, the outcome should look like this:

```
Split3_ID CU_ID order_id st_date                    sku Priority Delay CourseDate

1         25721 7907     2014-07-08 18:04:30.973    63  4        4     2014-07-08

2         25718 7910     2014-07-08 18:04:30.973    63  4        4     2014-07-08
3         25718 7910     2014-07-08 18:04:30.973    6   5        2     2014-07-12

4         25719 7908     2014-07-08 18:04:30.973    6   5        2     2014-07-12
5         25719 7908     2014-07-08 18:04:30.973    57  4        4     2014-07-08
6         25719 7908     2014-07-08 18:04:30.973    52  8        2     2014-07-14
```

Is there a way to accomplish this? I've got up to ten orders with the same order_id with no presorting, so my first attempts with CASE Statements ended up in a lot of writing.

The second, but not so important problem is, that there may be orders with the same priority from time to time under the same order_id. In this case I would like those to be treated just like CourseDate = st_date

Any help is highly appreciated, as I got a major brainfart at the moment ... ;)

Comment: Hi, as I can see the rows are grouped according to order_id, in the three row group order_id 7908 I can see the middle row has the lowest priority and hence has the st_date as CourseDate. is the row above (Split3_ID = 4) taking a course date of 2014-07-12 from the factr that the row with the lower priority has a delay of four? and is Split3_ID = 6 getting a CourseDate of 2014-07-14 becuase of the combined delays of Split3_ID 4 and 5?

Comment: yeah, that's how it works ... the solution is found already, thanks a lot though (see below for a very simple update statement) ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for this. I just saw your comments that you already had a solution. You may post it as answer as well.

```
 WITH c1 AS (
  SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY order_id ORDER BY priority)  
  FROM set_dates
)
, c2 AS ( 
  SELECT 
     *,
     first_date = (SELECT b.st_date FROM c1 b WHERE a.order_id = b.order_id AND b.rn = 1),
     delay_day = (SELECT SUM(delay) FROM c1 b WHERE a.order_id = b.order_id AND a.rn > b.rn) 
  FROM c1 a
)
SELECT 
  split3_id,cu_id,order_id,st_date,sku,priority,delay
  ,coursedate = DATEADD(dd,ISNULL(delay_day,0),first_date)
FROM c2
```

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/58adc/7)**

Comment: Perfect, CONVERT(varchar,DATEADD(dd,ISNULL(delay_day,0),first_date),23) !!